# php-active record oracle case sensative columns

Tags: php, oracle, phpactiverecord

I am using php-activerecord with oracle 10g. I am having issues with oracle columns being case sensitive.

```
class Employee extends ActiveRecord\Model{

static $table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';
static $primary_key = 'PERSON_ID';

static $belongs_to = array(
    array('supervisor', 'class_name' => 'Employee','foreign_key'=>'SUPERVISOR_ID')
);

}
```

Testing:

```
$employee = Employee::first();
echo $employee->supervisor_ID;     // Does not work - Oracle Columns are case sensitive
echo $employee->SUPERVISOR_ID;     // Prints ID

$employees = Employee::find('all', array('limit' => 10, 'include' => array('supervisor')));
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\UndefinedPropertyException' with message 'Undefined property: Employee->supervisor_id
```

Why is is looking for lower case supervisor_id when I defined the foreign key as SUPERVISOR_ID? Can I make it NOT case sensitive? I appreciate the help. Google has failed me today.

UPDATE:

I found this on the yii framework website:

"The cause is seems to be only partially Oracle-related. Oracle does not rely on case-sensitivity of column names as long as they are not specified within quotation marks. If so, it takes exact column name spelling as provided. Therefore, it seems that somewhere in Yii code underlying below ActiveRecord there have to be a part which escapes table name with quotation mark, making above mentioned problems."

^^ So it seems like I need to hack the phpactiverecord code somewhere to not have quotes around the column names. I guess phpactiverecord is crappy with oracle. Performance is supposed to be poor as well.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for an answer to this, I tracked it down to

Inflector.php

```
public function variablize($s) { 
       return str_replace(array('-','     '),array('_','_'),strtolower(trim($s))); 
}
```

When I change strolower to strtoupper, it worked.

Adding lower case attributes

```
static $alias_attribute = array(
      'supervisor_id' => 'SUPERVISOR_ID',
      'last_nm' => 'LAST_NM');
```

did not solve my issue. I hope someone out there has a better solution to this.